# How can I get access to knex/querybuilder raw in bookshelf.js?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

This is not working

```
let rawResult = await AuthorModel.query((qb) => {

  qb.column(Bookshelf.knex.raw('SELECT LEFT(authors.last_name, 1) AS first_char'));

});
```

and this is not working either:

```
let rawResult = await AuthorModel.query((qb) => {

  qb.column(AuthorModel.knex.raw('SELECT LEFT(authors.last_name, 1) AS first_char'));

});
```

And also this is not working:

```
let rawResult = await AuthorModel.query((qb) => {

  qb.column(qb.raw('SELECT LEFT(authors.last_name, 1) AS first_char'));

});
```

I am running out of ideas and options.